# Converting Gtiff to ASCII-Grid using QGIS gdal_translate?

Tags: qgis-2, esri-ascii-raster, geotiff-tiff

Gdal_translate implemented in QGIS is often recommended for converting to Ascii-Grid. My problem is that every output which is generated from my geotiff-raster layer is **binary instead of plain-text** in my Editor.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff D:/.../lu_krs_attr.tif D:/.../grid/test_grid.asc
```

How can I generate an Ascii-Grid-File in plain-text with header etc?

The GTiff was originally created in an Arc*-Software, it has 1 channel and a raster attribute table implemented (which is not assigned in QGIS and which I don't want to convert either).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the appropriate parameters to convert .asc file to geotiff using gdal\_translate?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/what-are-the-appropriate-parameters-to-convert-asc-file-to-geotiff-using-gdal-t)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, on the command line, look on Gis StackExchange ([convert geotiff to simple xyz elevation file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/convert-geotiff-to-simple-xyz-elevation-file) or [What are the appropriate parameters to convert .asc file to geotiff using gdal_translate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54483/grid-registration-issue-converting-from-geotiff-to-arc-ascii-grid) or ...):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff lu_krs_attr.tif test_grid.asc
```

convert the lu_krs_attr.tif to another tif file, even with asc. in the resulting filename

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid lu_krs_attr.tif test_grid.asc
```

convert the lu_krs_attr.tif to an ASCII grid

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff testgrid.asc test_grid.tif
```

reverse

And you have the command to use in QGIS

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The command "gdal_translate -of AAIGrid file.tif file.asc" ist the right one (and the only one, which was necessary). It turned out that the Userform in Qgis didnt' generate the right syntax concerning the "-of". 
I better learn the syntax for better results and even more translation-operations...

Answer (score 3):

While the main issue is fixed specifying the correct option `-of AAIGrid` instead of the wrong option `-of GTiff`, I had another problem "translating" geotiff files (downloaded from worldclim) to ASCII grid files in QGIS 2.6.1.

I solved it by typing `-ot Int32` after the translation command and before the file path:

```bash
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid -ot Int32 D:/.../lu_krs_attr.tif D:/.../grid/test_grid.asc
```

The idea is from http://clp-foss4g-workshop.readthedocs.org/en/latest/qgis_raster_resample.html

Comment: Modified the above slightly for the -ot to Int16 and it works on my Ubuntu machine: gdal_translate -of AAIGrid -ot Int16 D:/.../lu_krs_attr.tif D:/.../grid/test_grid.asc

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Int32` instead of `Int 32`?