# Convert large ASCII file to an image file

Tags: raster, ascii

I have a file of 5gb in a .asc form. The first lines are

`ncols         43200
 nrows         18000
 xllcorner     -180
 yllcorner     -60
 cellsize      0.0083333333333333
 NODATA_value  -9999`

It is a global layer.
Trying to convert it to .tif is not possible since maybe it is to big. 
I converted it using QGIS and raster --> translate to a .nc file, but it seems that the result is not as expected. I get values  for the north hemisphere above 20Lat only but not for the south(all value have the same.

Any suggestions on how can I convert it and in what form?

In the properties in Qgis the file has the following information:

**CRS**
EPSG:4326 - WGS 84
**Geographic
Extent**
-180.0000000000000000,-60.0000000000000000 : 180.0000000000000000,90.0000000000000000
**Unit**
degrees
**Width**
43200
**Height**
18000
**Data type**
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point
**GDAL Driver Description**
AAIGrid
**GDAL Driver Metadata**
Arc/Info ASCII Grid
**Dataset Description**
C:/lbii.asc
**Compression**

**Band 1**

**More information**

**Dimensions**
X: 43200 Y: 18000 Bands: 1
**Origin**
-180,90
**Pixel Size**
0.008333333333333333218,-0.008333333333333333218

When converting it to a .img i get the following image(almost same as .nc)

[image: Image in img format]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question instead of commenting on your own post.  I would agree that the data is corrupt, possibly at download. Because it is ASCII, a simple file scan would find binary corruption.

Comment: Yes you are right. The data were corrupt. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gdal from out the command line should do the trick, and will be one of the fastest options! Now the question is in which format you want it. As it is quite big I would suggest using the format binary grid. To make such a translation, you need to make use of a commandline with gdal installed in it. Supposing you use windows: Press the windows key and type in osgeo4wshell. Navigate to **C:** by typing C:, and type in the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of "ENVI" C:\Ibii.asc C:\Ibii_Visual_Image.flt
```

For questions concerning the use of gdal, have a look [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).
Or search [online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77917/converting-gtiff-to-ascii-grid-using-qgis-gdal-translate) for similar situations.